# How to pull data from every sheet in a Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I have reached the limit of 200 sheets/tabs and I want Sheet200's column 1 to be populated with all the B2 cells from every other sheet, how can I do that?

Doing it manually like =Sheet1!B2, =Sheet2!B2, ... Sheet199!B2 is not helpful.

Comment: you will need a script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Save all of the Bs in Column1 of sheet 200

```
function getAllTheB2s() {
  const ss = ScriptProperties.getActive();
  const shts = ss.getSheets();
  const sh = shts[199];
  shts.filter((e,i) => i < 199).forEach(s => {
    let vs = s.getRange("B1:B" + s.getLastRow()).getValues()
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,1, vs.length,1).setValues(vs);
    //SpreadsheetApp.flush();//might be necessary
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. When would the flush be necessary?

Comment: I wasn't sure in the getLastRow() would work every time without it.

Answer (score 0):

On option using formulas is to use `INDIRECT` built-in function.

Add `=INDIRECT('Sheet'&ROW()&'!B2')` to A1 then fill down or copy `A1` and paste it to `A2:A200`.

If you want to start in another row, let say row 3, replace `ROW()` by `ROW() - 2`.